# How to fix duplicatation of object in angular.forEach?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Please assist me How can i fix it.

```
    schema.controller('schemaDetailCtrl', function($scope, ajaxCall, $location) {
    $scope.storeDetails = [
     {
      "storeName": "Test Store",
      "zipCode": "201301",
      "idenNo": "999999"
     },
     {
      "storeName": "Test2 Store",
      "zipCode": "201014",
      "idenNo": "200037"
     },
     {
      "storeName": "Test3 Store",
      "zipCode": "201014",
      "idenNo": "200137"
     }
   ];

    $scope.zipcodes = new Array();
       angular.forEach($scope.storeDetails, function(store) {
       this.push(store.zipCode);
       console.log(store.zipCode);
    }, $scope.zipcodes);



    Expected Output :
    201301
    201014
    201014

    Actual Output: 
    Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.20/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=zipcode%20in%20zipcodes&p1=string%3A201014
```

Comment: you're getting that error because you are pushing the same value into a repeater multiple times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Everyone for your answers, Now I used for loop insteed of angular.forEach and it sounds good.

```
for(var i = 0; i < $scope.storeDetails.length; i++) {
    var store = $scope.storeDetails[i];
    if(contains($scope.zipcodes, store.zipCode) === false) {
        $scope.zipcodes.push(store.zipCode);
    }
}

function contains(a, obj) {
    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] === obj) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: if this helped, can you please mark it as correct answer so that its clear that this is the actual answer and we don't have to scroll

Answer (score 1):

The issue has nothing to do with your `forEach` directly. It is being thrown from the view and can be resolved by adding `track by` to the `ng-repeat` statement:

```
<div ng-repeat="zip in zipcodes track by $index">
```

If you don't want duplicates in the array that would be a separate issue to filter them out.

Reference [ng-repeat docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of copying the zip codes into another array to show in your view, you could just iterate over the storeDetails array and then reference the zipCode property to display it.

```
<ul ng-repeat="store in storeDetails">
  <li>{{store.zipCode}}</li>
</ul>
```

This would circumvent the issue of duplicates in your array.

Comment: Devitall, This can be done in html but i want to do it in controller that is in js.